# Row Copying between tabs

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on an attendance tracker for multiple teams. I want to have multiple tabs; one tab per team, but I also want one master tab with all the names and attendance on it without having to do it all manually. I also need the master sheet to be alphabetized. I have no clue how to even begin writing a code for this, not even sure if its possible without using google scripts (and I have no experience in that), but if it is possible I would love to find out how to do it.

[This is tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3lnJ.png)

[This is tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh9E8.png)

[This is tab 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48CYj.png)

[And this is where I need each row to go and be alphabetized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTUk3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit
(following OP's request)

Tickboxes canNOT be transferred.
To turn columns with `TRUE` `FALSE` to tickboxes do the following.
Select all of them and go to `Insert` --> `Tick box`

---

There is no need for a script.
Please use the following formula:

```
=QUERY({'Team 1'!A2:F;'Team 2'!A2:F;'Team 3'!A2:F},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1")
```

More info about [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Okay that worked, but it now shows true/false instead of checkboxes on the final sheet. Do you know if there is a way to keep/convert those readings to checkboxes

Comment: Glad I could help :)